# Conditional copy of values from one column to another columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks something like this:

```
 name        job             jobchange_rank   date
Thisguy      Developer       1                2012
Thisguy      Analyst         2                2014
Thisguy      Data Scientist  3                2015
Anotherguy   Developer       1                2018
```

The jobchange_rank represents the each individual's (based on name) ranked change in position, where rank nr 1 represent his/her first position nr 2 his/her second position, etc.

Now for the fun part. I want to create a new column where I can see a person's previous job, something like this:

```
 name        job             jobchange_rank   date   previous_job
Thisguy      Developer       1                2012   None
Thisguy      Analyst         2                2014   Developer
Thisguy      Data Scientist  3                2015   Analyst
Anotherguy   Developer       1                2018   None
```

I've created the following code to get the "None" values where there was no job change:

```
df.loc[df['jobchange_rank'].sub(df['jobchange_rank'].min()) == 0, 'previous_job'] = 'None'
```

Sadly, I can't seem to figure out how to get the values from the other column where the needed condition applies.

Any help is more then welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes that your DataFrame is sorted by `name` and `jobchange_rank`, if that is not the case, sort first.

---

```
# df = df.sort_values(['name', 'jobchange_rank'])

m = df['name'].eq(df['name'].shift())
df['job'].shift().where(m)
```

```
0          NaN
1    Developer
2      Analyst
3          NaN
Name: job, dtype: object
```

Or using a `groupby` + `shift` (assuming at least sorted by `jobchange_rank`)

```
df.groupby('name')['job'].shift()
```

```
0          NaN
1    Developer
2      Analyst
3          NaN
Name: job, dtype: object
```

---

Although the `groupby` + `shift` is more concise, on larger inputs, if your data is already sorted like your example, it may be faster to avoid the `groupby` and use the first solution.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply and also the recommendations! It works perfectly.